# acts-as-taggable-on 5.0 and rails 7 association problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Just updated the project to rails 7 and the only compatible version of ActsAsTaggableOn for the project is version 5.

On add the gem, add the valid param to the controller and done the migrations, bit I get this error

```
Rails couldn't find a valid model for ::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.
```

I tested put the following `acts_as_taggable_on :tags` and `acts_as_taggable` both with the same result.

If I change the name to `acts_as_taggable_on :modelname` I dont get the error but the model says invalid value `unknown attribute 'tag_list' for modelname`

I tried to manually add the column to the model but still don't works.

Comment: [Version 9](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/versions/9.0.0) was just released. It is better to use that version for rails 7.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the last version fixed the issue